# Adroid 11: can't load file from external storage

Tags: android

I want to choose pdf file from Downloads folder and send it to chat. But this document is not loaded. When I use Android 9, it works ok. I am confused that when I receive `uri`, I have this value: `content://0@media/external/file/` . what is `0@media`?

Comment: `@media` is a content-provider

Comment: @A Farmanbar, Yes, I know. But why before `@media` is `0` ? Is it ok?

Comment: I'm not sure why it started with `0` however it's related to OS specifications.

Comment: I get messege `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/1.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)` but all permissions I have.

Comment: it shows your URI is okay and points to a valid file. but you have not permission to read or write it.

Comment: @Monica are u aware of scoped storage in android 10+ ??

Comment: @Monica can u share ur manifest file ?

Comment: @DrHowdyDoo
 `    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

Comment: "I want to choose pdf file from Downloads folder" -- you are working with content, not files, and content does not have to be a file on the filesystem that your app can access. Use the `Uri` directly, please, using things like `ContentResolver` and its `openInputStream()` method to read in the content identified by that `Uri`.

Answer (score 3):

On Android 11, apps can no longer access files in any other app's dedicated, app-specific directory within external storage. To protect user privacy, on devices that run Android 11 or higher, the system further restricts your app's access to other apps' private directories.

You have to use Storage Access Framework to access external storage in android 10+

You can use [ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT) intent, which opens the system's file picker app.

Have a look : [Open a file](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#open-file)